# Case within Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I have to get an instructor approval date from a table called section.  If that table doesn't have the date (null), then I have to get a date from offering table, and even if that table doesn't have what I am looking for, then from Term table.

AND if all three are null, then I need to get absoluteExpireDate in same manners as instructorapprovaldate.

AND if absoluteExpireDate is also null in all three tables, then I need to get WaitList date in similar fashion.

How do I create a case statement to handle that?

so far here's what I have:

```
SELECT  @dInstructApprDate = case when a.InstructorApprovalDate is null  
        then
             select @dInstructApprDate = instructorapprovaldate 
             from SSS_OfferingAcademicPeriods   
             where SSS_OfferingRegPeriods.SSS_OfferingsID = @lSSS_OfferingsID
```

I am not sure why it doesn't like me using select statement within "THEN"

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I got so far for the function:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SSS_GetInstructorApprovalDate](@lSSS_SectionsID INT)      
 RETURNS VARCHAR(20)    
 AS      

          BEGIN      

  DECLARE   
 @dInstructApprDate DATETIME,  
 @dAddDropDate  DATETIME,  
 @lTemp    INT,  
 @lSSS_OfferingsID INT,  
 @lSSS_TermsID  INT  

 SET @lTemp = 0  

 SELECT   
 @lTemp = 1  
 WHERE   
 EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SSS_SectionAcademicPeriods WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE SSS_SectionsID = @lSSS_SectionsID)  

--Fetch from section level, if present - Begin  
 IF @lTemp = 1  
BEGIN  

  SELECT  @dInstructApprDate = case when a.InstructorApprovalDate is null  
  then   
   (select instructorapprovaldate from SSS_OfferingAcademicPeriods where SSS_OfferingRegPeriods.SSS_OfferingsID = @lSSS_OfferingsID)

  else   
 InstructorApprovalDate  
end   
  FROM  
   SSS_SectionAcademicPeriods a WITH (NOLOCK)  
  where   
   SSS_SectionsID = @lSSS_SectionsID
```

Comment: You should provide the complete query

Comment: Consider using `coalesce` instead of case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you're checking for null, you could use `Coalesce`:

```
select coalesce
(
      (select 1 a where 1=2) --returns null
    , (select 2 a where 2=3) --returns null
    , (select 3 a where 4=4) --returns result
    , 100 --default
) x
```

For me this would be cleaner / easier to read than a case statement, and I suspect would perform just as well.

Based on the code & description included in your question, for you this would look something like the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SSS_GetInstructorApprovalDate](@lSSS_SectionsID INT)      
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)    
AS      
BEGIN      

    DECLARE @dInstructApprDate  DATETIME 
    ,       @dAddDropDate       DATETIME
    ,       @lSSS_OfferingsID   INT
    ,       @lSSS_TermsID       INT  
    --,     @lTemp              INT = 0

    --I suspect you don't want this bit; but uncomment if it's required (i.e. if you only want a value when there's a matching record in the secion table, but the record's approval date's null
    --SELECT top 1 @lTemp = 1 
    --FROM SSS_SectionAcademicPeriods WITH (NOLOCK) 
    --WHERE SSS_SectionsID = @lSSS_SectionsID

    --Fetch from section level, if present - Begin  
    --IF @lTemp = 1  
    --BEGIN  

        SELECT @dInstructApprDate = coalesce
        (
            (
                SELECT InstructorApprovalDate       
                FROM SSS_SectionAcademicPeriods with(nolock)
                where SSS_SectionsID = @lSSS_SectionsID
            )
            ,
            (
                select InstructorApprovalDate 
                from SSS_OfferingAcademicPeriods 
                where SSS_OfferingsID = @lSSS_OfferingsID
            )
            ,
            (
                select InstructorApprovalDate 
                from SSS_TermsAcademicPeriods 
                where SSS_OfferingsID = @lSSS_TermsID
            )

            ,
            (
                SELECT AbsoluteExpireDate       
                FROM SSS_SectionAcademicPeriods with(nolock)
                where SSS_SectionsID = @lSSS_SectionsID
            )
            ,
            (
                select AbsoluteExpireDate        
                from SSS_OfferingAcademicPeriods 
                where SSS_OfferingsID = @lSSS_OfferingsID
            )
            ,
            (
                select AbsoluteExpireDate        
                from SSS_TermsAcademicPeriods 
                where SSS_OfferingsID = @lSSS_TermsID
            )
            ,
            (
                SELECT WaitListDate     
                FROM SSS_SectionAcademicPeriods with(nolock)
                where SSS_SectionsID = @lSSS_SectionsID
            )
            ,
            (
                select WaitListDate      
                from SSS_OfferingAcademicPeriods 
                where SSS_OfferingsID = @lSSS_OfferingsID
            )
            ,
            (
                select WaitListDate      
                from SSS_TermsAcademicPeriods 
                where SSS_OfferingsID = @lSSS_TermsID
            )

        )
    --END
    return cast(@dInstructApprDate as varchar(20)) --probably 

END
```

NB: Depending on how long each query takes you may want to approach it slightly differently.  Here's an alternate / let me know how it suits:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SSS_GetInstructorApprovalDate](@lSSS_SectionsID INT)      
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)    
AS      
BEGIN      

    DECLARE @dInstructApprDate  DATETIME 
    ,       @dInstructApprDate2 DATETIME 
    ,       @dInstructApprDate3 DATETIME 
    ,       @dAddDropDate       DATETIME
    ,       @lSSS_OfferingsID   INT
    ,       @lSSS_TermsID       INT  
    --,     @lTemp              INT = 0

    --I suspect you don't want this bit; but uncomment if it's required (i.e. if you only want a value when there's a matching record in the secion table, but the record's approval date's null
    --SELECT top 1 @lTemp = 1 
    --FROM SSS_SectionAcademicPeriods WITH (NOLOCK) 
    --WHERE SSS_SectionsID = @lSSS_SectionsID

    --Fetch from section level, if present - Begin  
    --IF @lTemp = 1  
    --BEGIN  


        SELECT  @dInstructApprDate  = InstructorApprovalDate        
        ,       @dInstructApprDate2 = AbsoluteExpireDate
        ,       @dInstructApprDate3 = WaitListDate
        FROM SSS_SectionAcademicPeriods with(nolock)
        where SSS_SectionsID = @lSSS_SectionsID

        if @dInstructApprDate is null 
            select  @dInstructApprDate  = InstructorApprovalDate        
            ,       @dInstructApprDate2 = isnull(@dInstructApprDate2, AbsoluteExpireDate)
            ,       @dInstructApprDate3 = isnull(@dInstructApprDate3, WaitListDate)
            from SSS_OfferingAcademicPeriods 
            where SSS_OfferingsID = @lSSS_OfferingsID

        if @dInstructApprDate is null 
            select  @dInstructApprDate  = InstructorApprovalDate    
            ,       @dInstructApprDate2 = isnull(@dInstructApprDate2, AbsoluteExpireDate)
            ,       @dInstructApprDate3 = isnull(@dInstructApprDate3, WaitListDate
            from SSS_TermsAcademicPeriods 
            where SSS_OfferingsID = @lSSS_TermsID


        set @dInstructApprDate = coalesce(@dInstructApprDate, @dInstructApprDate2, @dInstructApprDate3)

    --END
    return cast(@dInstructApprDate as varchar(20)) --probably 

END
```

Answer (score 1):

a bit hard to say without having the whole query, what `a` stands for? Looks like your `case` is part of the bigger query, but

```
SELECT
    @dInstructApprDate = 
         case
             when a.InstructorApprovalDate is null  
             then 
             (
                 select o.InstructorApprovalDate 
                 from SSS_OfferingAcademicPeriods as o
                 where o.SSS_OfferingsID = @lSSS_OfferingsID
             )
-- ...
-- you have from clause here?
-- ...
```

I think your query could be greatly simplified, but can't say until I see the whole query

**update**

```
select @dInstructApprDate = InstructorApprovalDate
from SSS_SectionAcademicPeriods
where SSS_SectionsID = @lSSS_SectionsID

if @dInstructApprDate is null
    select @dInstructApprDate = instructorapprovaldate
    from SSS_OfferingAcademicPeriods
    where SSS_OfferingsID = @lSSS_OfferingsID
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am creating a function that will be used in a separate stored proc.  All this function is supposed to do is get one of the dates based on the sectionID

Answer (score 1):

You need only one variable assignment per select e.g.

```
SELECT  @dInstructApprDate = case when a.InstructorApprovalDate is null  
        then  (select  instructorapprovaldate from SSS_OfferingAcademicPeriods)
....
```

But better yet split it into separate selects - easier to read, easier to maintain better for server to execute, e.g.

```
SELECT  @dInstructApprDate = InstructorApprovalDate FROM section

IF @dInstructApprDate IS NULL -- if it's null after first assignmnent
     SELECT  @dInstructApprDate = InstructorApprovalDate FROM SSS_OfferingAcademicPeriods

IF @dInstructApprDate IS NULL -- if it's still null
     SELECT  @dInstructApprDate = TermDate FROM Term
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **IF statement** in this case.

**CASE is used to choose a scalar value**, (which can also be retrieved with a query).
IF can be used choose the relevant query for the relevant case in a more readable way.

Your code should look something like this (in pseudo):

```
IF(Some condition)
BEGIN
     SELECT ...
     FROM...   

END
ELSE IF (Some condition)
BEGIN
    SELECT ...
    FROM...   
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) as shown below. Since you want the value from a table that you first encounter, you need to check `IS NOT NULL` first. If the value is `NOT NULL` the `CASE` statement stops there.

This is exactly how [`COALESCE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) works. So, you can replace `CASE` statement with `COALESCE`

See demo -

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00c93/5)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (     id int    , type varchar(50)    );
CREATE TABLE t2 (     id int    , type varchar(50)    );
CREATE TABLE t3 (     id int    , type varchar(50)    );


insert into t1 values (1, 'one');
insert into t1 values (10, null);
insert into t1 values (15, null);
insert into t1 values (20, null);
insert into t2 values (10, 'ten from table t2');
insert into t3 values (15, 'fifteen from table t3');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN TYPE IS NOT NULL THEN TYPE
       WHEN  (SELECT TYPE FROM t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id) IS NOT NULL
            THEN (SELECT TYPE FROM t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
       ELSE  (SELECT TYPE FROM t3 WHERE t3.id = t1.id)
       END
FROM t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00c93/5/0)**:

```
| ID |              COLUMN_1 |
|----|-----------------------|
|  1 |                   one |
| 10 |     ten from table t2 |
| 15 | fifteen from table t3 |
| 20 |                (null) |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT id, 
      COALESCE(TYPE,
              (SELECT TYPE FROM t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id),
              (SELECT TYPE FROM t3 WHERE t3.id = t1.id))
FROM t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00c93/5/1)**:

```
| ID |              COLUMN_1 |
|----|-----------------------|
|  1 |                   one |
| 10 |     ten from table t2 |
| 15 | fifteen from table t3 |
| 20 |                (null) |
```